# Fast way to check if I'm adding duplicate css (if possible in coda)?

Tags: html, css, editor, coda

Is there an easy way to check if I'm adding duplicate css lines to my file? I'm currently adding on to the existing style sheet and am now using command+f in my editor (Coda) to find if the class has already been used but this is by far the fastest way to do this.

To be perfectly clear: Let's say I'm writing to add a margin to class '.test', how do I make sure I am not repeating '.test' in my document?

Is there something in Coda that can do this, or in other editors?

Comment: You can use CSSBurner (http://www.cssburner.com) to locate redundant/repeat selectors and rules and all other types of CSS that can be removed or reduced. Only problem is that it is an online tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some text editors will underline duplicated css.

Good text editor: [atom text editor](https://atom.io/)

some tips for you so you wont need any text editor auto checkers:

- 1. Keep your css in order.

example:

```
body{}
navbar{}
footer{}
```

- 2 Use comments to know what you are styling so it will be easy to continue after brake.
- 3.keep class/id names clear! For example use `.navbar / #navbar` Dont use something like `.thisasdafclassbadexample`